# How to stop Play server started from Eclipse launcher

Tags: java, playframework

A very noob question, I know. The `play eclipsify` command creates two Eclipse launchers, so I started the server (in DEV mode), then I wrote a test and wanted to run in TEST mode. This is impossible as long as port 9000 is already bound. I need a way to stop the Play webserver. I tried with `play stop` but it complains about missing `server.pid`. I don't know where Eclipse puts this pid file, and even if I knew it I think `play stop` wouldn't work outside of the project directory.

BTW, I am on Play 1.2.4

Comment: its Netty not Jetty. Tags updated to reflect.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I updated the question, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **BIG RED SQUARED** button for stopping! Shame on me :P

Now it's very strange but if I start my app from the Eclipse launcher, the SASS module doesn't compile SCSS files before serving them, so the browser doesn't get valid CSS. If I start the server with play run everything works as expected. Like @Codemwnci said it's better to start from the command line, even if I think this can't be the definitive way...

Comment: could be related to this: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1413-eclipsify-should-set-up-playplugins-exclusion#ticket-1413-1

Answer (score 3):

`play stop` will only end a process which has been started with `play start`. When using `play start` it will create the associated `server.pid` file to allow the stop command to function as expected.

Eclipse is likely using `play run` which runs the process inline. Therefore, you should be able to stop the server from within eclipse.

Comment: I tend not to use Eclipse, but even when using intellij, I use the command line to launch the server. It doesn't answer what Eclipse does, but it should solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my intent :) I can even start the server from Eclipse and kill it from the terminal (by PID). I was just wondering how this can happen without opening another terminal window